# php session always created on refresh

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am new to PHP so have a very basic question
I creating a page I am creating a page initially with user id and password, once user id and password are entered and submit is clicked, AJAX is called to validate that against database.
once validation done I want to refresh the page which show more option to user
I was thinking to use session
but every time I refresh the page a new session is created
I put this at the top of the page as a test and always when F5 is press I see "new session" on top of the page

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
    echo("new session");
}
else
{
    echo("old session");
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what `session_start` does. From the documentation: "session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie."

Comment: `$_SESSION` will never be set before `session_start()` is called. You should call `session_start()` at the top of each of your session-enabled pages. It will not overwrite an existing session. Instead, it will  give you access to the user's current session or create one if none exists yet. If you want to explicitly start a new session, use `session_destroy()` first, then `session_start()`.

Answer (score 4):

`session_start` must be called always before anything related to a session. After calling it, you can get or set values of the `$_SESSION` variable.

[Reference](http://php.net/session_start).

Your code should be:

```
<?php
session_start(); // always call this at top
if (!isset($_SESSION['has_been_here'])){
    $_SESSION['has_been_here'] = true;
    echo("new session");
}
else
{
    echo("already been here");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that answered my question. Now I got a new problem. I have a AJAX that is called after submit is preseed.

Comment: Start another question

Answer (score 1):

From php.net:

```
session_start — Start new or resume existing session
```

That means you have to start your session with

```
session_start();
```

on every page, in the first line, which will start or resume it. Check the php.net [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), it will help you understand how to handle and check sessions correctly.